Find a geo coordinate lies on street or road with OSM map
I Have a list of geo coordinate points. I need to mark them valid or Invalid. How I can check with osm(Open Street MAP) map or other free source with help of python code. Is there any free API where I can pass my geocoordinate and get result as it lies or street or road.

You can use Overpass-API with a query like this:
[out:json];
way[highway](around:15,47.54008,4.44047);
(._;>;);
out;

This one looks around highways nearly 15 meters from the coordinates 47.54008,4.44047.
With Python, you can consume the API with the overpy module.
